# Activity lag on Jelly Bean

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a lot of activities but all do the same thing but each shows different text in the .xml layout. I noticed there is a lag for like 4 seconds every time an activity starts. That lag happens on Jelly Bean devices specifically.

Here is how the classes look like:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    setContentView(R.layout.general);

     TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     final EditText txt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     final EditText txt3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

     txt1.setText(getString(R.string.K_item1));
     txt2.setText(getString(R.string.k1_0));
     txt3.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.k1_0tr));

fade = new AlphaAnimation(0,1);
fade.setDuration(500);
  txt1.startAnimation(fade);
  txt2.startAnimation(fade);}
```

The manifest xml file looks like this:

```
android:versionCode="4"
android:versionName="1.0.1" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/imamicn"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name="com.androidbook.balagha.welcomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=“KtbActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="Ktb1_40"></activity>
    <activity android:name="Ktb41_80"></activity>
```

I have texts for the title, the main message, and the third one shows up when pulling the drawer. 
I tried to disable all animations in the activity, but that didn’t solve the problem actives still lag when first started, and when text fade animation enabled, it doesn't run because the lag is longer than its duration.  Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I did that but still lags, even when the class code commented out with the exception for setContentView(R.layout.general);

Comment: Ok, are you directly extending Activity or some other class?